# Similarity of Jordan cannonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

I'm struggling with this question:
Determine all possible Jordan canonical forms (up to the ordering of the Jordan blocks) for a 6 ×6 matrix
A, if A has an eigenvalue 2 with algebraic multiplicity 6, and geometric multiplicity 3. **Explain why the
obtained Jordan canonical forms are not similar (hint: consider (J −2I)<sup>2</sup>).**

I have obtained the Jordan canonical forms, however, I don't understand how can they not be similar. It seems to me that Jordan canonical forms of the same matrix always have to be similar.
If A has canonical forms J<sub>1</sub> and J<sub>2</sub>, then A = PJ<sub>1</sub>P<sup>-1</sup> and  A = SJ<sub>2</sub>S<sup>-1</sup> for some matrices P and S. Therefore, PJ<sub>1</sub>P<sup>-1</sup> = SJ<sub>2</sub>S<sup>-1</sup> => J<sub>1</sub> = P<sup>-1</sup>SJ<sub>2</sub>S<sup>-1</sup>P = (P<sup>-1</sup>S)J<sub>2</sub>(P<sup>-1</sup>S)<sup>-1</sup>. So, J<sub>1</sub> and J<sub>2</sub> are similar.

If you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi Perkunas. A given matrix $A$ has one and only one Jordan canonical form (up to rearrangements of the Jordan blocks). In the question though, you are not given an explicit matrix $A$, you just have some clues (the eigenvalues and their multiplicities). The question asks what are all the possible Jordan forms that $A$ could have given the partial information that you have on $A$. It’s clear that if you know $A$ your answer will be its Jordan canonical form, but since you don’t know $A$ exactly, you can have many cases (e.g. two 1x1 blocks and one 4x4 block, or maybe three 2x2 blocks, etc…).

Comment: …and the matrix $A$ will be similar to one of the Jordan forms that you listed (and only one of these), even if you don’t know which one because of the partial information you have about $A$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili, oh, so the Jordan forms that I've determined belong to different matrices and that's why they can be not similar! It makes sense now, thank you for your help.